# PHP form submission with refreshing

Tags: php, refresh, blogs, submission

first time posting on here so I apologise for any bad habits.
I recently started an online youtube tutorial on php and how to create a blog.
I ended up getting occupied with other things and have come back to try an finish what I started and 2 things have happened. 1: my tutorials have been deleted off youtube(must of been a copyrright issue) and second I've completely forgot the method used. I assume if I was a seasoned coder this would be easy to decipher but I'm having no luck after trying for days now.

This code is for the submission form for my blog. The blog is working in the sense of if I manually input my HTML into the SQL database but all I seem to get if I use this form is a refresh of the submission page with all the information gone. No information is added to the database.

Anybody have an idea?I had a good search around the site but I ran into a dead end due to my lack of knowledge on what I was actually searching for (lots of solutions regarding javascript)

All help will be appreciated.

Sincerely

SGT Noob

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();



if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

$username = ($_SESSION['username']);

}

else { 
header('Location: ../index.php');


die();

}

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
if ($_POST['submit']) {

$title = $_POST['Post_Title'];
$content = $_POST['Post_Content'];
$date = $_POST['Post_Date'];

include_once("../admin/connection.php");


$sql = "INSERT INTO `posts` (Post_Title, Post_Content, Post_Date) 
                                                    VALUES         ('$title','$content','$date')";

mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql);

echo "Post has been added to the database";


}
else {
header('Location: index.php');
die();

}


?> 


 <html> 
 <div>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.9/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>



 <title> Insert Post </title>

 </head>

<div>


<body>
<div id= 'cmssubmissionform'>

<form action="" method="post">
<p> 
<h1> Post Title</h1>

<input type="text" name= "Post_Title"/>
</p>


<h1> Post Date</h1>
<input type="text" name= "Post_Date"/>
</p>

<p>
<h1>Post Content </h1>
<textarea name="Post_Content"></textarea>
<script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'Post_Content' );
    </script>


 </p>


 <p>
<input type = "submit" value="submit" />
</p>
</form>

</div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Your query is susceptible to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Always **prepare**, **bind** and **execute** your queries to prevent any kind of SQL injection.

Comment: You don't have anything named `submit` to check for `$_POST['submit']`. You probably missed `name="submit"` in the submit input.

Comment: Actually, sql injection is not a risk with mysqli_query = http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php ("multiple queries are not supported"). Anyway, "prepare, bind and execute" is a good advice.

Answer (score 0):

try this

in your from change to

```
    <input type = "submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
```

You forgot to put the name attribute

The php

```
              <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

     session_start();
     include_once("../admin/connection.php");



      if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

      $username = ($_SESSION['username']);

      }

      else { 
        header('Location: ../index.php');


        die();

      }

      if (isset($_POST['submit'])){


          $title = $_POST['Post_Title'];
          $content = $_POST['Post_Content'];
          $date = $_POST['Post_Date'];


          $sql = "INSERT INTO `posts` (`Post_Title`, `Post_Content`, `Post_Date`) 
                 VALUES ('$title','$content','$date')";


          if(mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql)){

            echo "Post has been added to the database";
          }else{

              header('Location: index.php');
              die();


          }




      }

      ?>
```

Note I also changed your SQL statement to

```
   INSERT INTO `posts` (`Post_Title`, `Post_Content`, `Post_Date`) 
             VALUES ('$title','$content','$date
```

Notice the back ticks for the table fields

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
if ($_POST['submit']) {
```

with

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

and then replace

```
<input type = "submit" value="submit" />
```

with

```
<input type ="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

However, at this stage I would highly suggest starting over with a different tutorial.

Also, as has been mentioned in the comments, whenever you take arguments from a user and put them into a database query, you must absolutely make sure that the strings do not manipulate the query (imagine someone wrote `` 0'; DROP TABLE `blog`; -- `` in the date field (and "blog" were the name of your blog post table). That would be quite catastrophic, wouldn't it?

So when you handle input data, either use the prepare and bind methods of the mysqli package, or pass the strings through the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function first.